# Get the height of a menu on page load

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a menu, and with:

```
var headed = $('#menu-main_menu li');
headed.hover(
    function() {
        var subed  = $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').height();
        var headwi = $(this).width();
        $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').css({'top': -subed, 'width': headwi }).show();
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').hide();
        return false;
    }
);
```

Here is a jsfiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/moabi/VDZYV/2/
and as you can see, it doesn't get the height on the first shot. What did i do wrong ?
(the menu is at the bottom of the page, so I want the sub-menu to go up, this is why i put the negative value)
thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's because your sub menu items are floating next to each other in a horizontal line by default, so initially the height of the sub menu is only the height of one of the items, not all added together.

If you set the width of the sub menu first then its height will be correct as the items will have stacked, so something like:

```
headed.hover(function() {

    var subm = $('ul.sub-menu', $(this)).show();
    subm
        .width($(this).width())
        .css('top', -subm.height());

}, function() {
    $('ul.sub-menu', $(this)).hide();
    return false;
});
```

What might be easier though is to tweak the CSS so the sub menu items stack vertically naturally, so:

```
#access .menu-header .sub-menu li
{
float: none;
}
```

Comment: exact ! i set the sub-menu width and now it gets the correct height...thx

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't get the correct height until the HTML is rendered on the screen. To work around this `show()` the sub-menu first, THEN change it's `top` position:

```
var headed = $('#menu-main_menu li');
headed.hover(function() {
  var sub = $(this).find('ul.sub-menu');
  var headwi = $(this).width();
  sub.css('width', headwi);
  sub.css('top', -1000);  // temporary top postion
  sub.show();
  sub.css('top', -(sub.height()));  // real top position
}, function() {
  $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').hide();
  return false;
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2wKJQ/

**EDIT**

A second example that keeps the `visibility` hidden to prevent any flickering and has a `fadeIn/fadeOut`:

```
var headed = $('#menu-main_menu li');
headed.hover(function() {
   var sub = $(this).find('ul.sub-menu');
    var headwi = $(this).width();
    sub.css('width', headwi);
    sub.css('top', -1000);
    sub.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    sub.show();
    sub.css('top', -(sub.height()));
    sub.css('visibility', 'visible');
    sub.hide();
    sub.fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').fadeOut();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: ok thank you, but this means that if i want to apply a fadeIn/fadeOut it won't apply on the first hover ?

Comment: You can still do a `fadeIn()` - just `hide()` the element again after setting the real `top` position: http://jsfiddle.net/2wKJQ/1/